# How to install PyAudio via Virtual Environment in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv

So I am using a venv (virtual environment) for one of my python projects and need to install PyAudio for it. I am using PyCharm for the venv.

When I try to install PyCharm usually it comes up with 'Command errored out with exit status: 1'

How can I install PyAudio into my venv properly (I know PyAudio needs to be installed differently I just don't know how to do it in the venv)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by

```
pip install pipwin
```

And then

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

This installs the .whl package automatically

Comment: I can't use pip as I am in a virtual environment using PyCharm - the only way to install is to go to settings then get it from there. However, I will try to install pipwin from there then pyaudio and see if that works

Comment: Uhmm you can use pip in virtual environments. I also use pycharm. How else are you supposed to install packages in virtual envs. Go check your settings. Pip can be used

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed my problem. I found the PyAudio file in my normal python (Python 3.9 64-bit) and transferred it to my venv (Python 3.8 64-bit) and now it works fine!